# Решение задачи Коши "Методом Адамса"

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Доброго времени суток!

Никак не могу разобраться с методом Адамса.

Имеется система [image: Имеется система]

Нужно написать программу, которая решает Задачи Коши для данной системы, с помощью метода Адамса третьего порядка.

Никак не могу разобраться с самим алгоритмом и методом. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей.

http://www.astro.tsu.ru/ChIntODY/text/5_1.html

На данный момент опираюсь вот на эту статью, но никак не могу понять что то выдает метод Адамса на выходе.

Был бы рад любым скинутым материалам, возможно учебникам и готовым примерам, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

На входе (каждого шага) метода Адамса: точное значение (вектора) X в начальной точке по времени, и приближенное значение в k следующих точек по времени, с шагом lambda/k. 
На выходе - точные значения X в этих точках.

Вектор X, в твоем случае - двумерный: [x,y]. 
В статье, нижний индекс используется не для обозначения компонента вектора, а для обозначения значения X, на k-м шаге:  X_i = X( X_0 + i *lambda/k ) .
Возможно тебя запутало именно это.

Приближенные начальные значения для под шагов обычно получают каким-то другим методом: например методом Ньютона.

Длину lambda рекомендую взять существенно меньше 1 (характерное время изменения величин для твоей системы уравнений).